# How to train a SVM by using LDA

Tags: c++, opencv, svm, pca, linear-discriminant

I am using C++ with OpenCV 3.0.

I have a training data matrix with features that I have extracted of some images (*trainData*). The size of this matrix is 2750x1104 because I have 2750 images (positive and negative) with 1104 features each. I have other matrix of 2750x1 with the labels (*trainLabels*).

- **trainData**: 2750 images x 1104 features.
- **trainLabels**: 2750 images x 1 label per column

With this information I want to train a SVM and I would like to evaluate the performance of using PCA (Principal Component Analysis), LDA (Linear Discriminative Analysis) and a combination of both. I have applied PCA without problems but when I use LDA I obtain a matrix of 2750x1 (*projected*) that the SVM cannot use as input.

I have used this [link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/64165/how-to-perform-linear-discriminant-analysis-with-opencv/), but they do not employ SVM.

This is the code:

```
LDA lda(trainData, trainLabels, num_components);
Mat eigenvectors = lda.eigenvectors();
Mat projected = lda.project(trainData);
```

I have selected *num_components* as 1 because I have two classes (person & no person).

And these are my results:

- **eigenvectors**: 1104 rows x 1 column
- **projected**: 2750 rows x 1 column

As far I understand *eigenvectors* should be 1104x1104 and *projected* 2750x1104 so the SVM can be trained with the matrix *projected*.

I don't know if I am really wrong in the code, maybe I do not understand correctly how LDA works. If so, could you give me some tips? In fact, could I train a SVM with LDA?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: first of all PCA is not "Program Analysis Components" but "Principal Component Analysis". Second of all LDA (Linear Discriminant Analysis) is a classifier, not dimensionality reduction technique. LDA is "of the same level of abstraction" as SVM, not as PCA.

Comment: You are right, thanks! I'm going to edit that.

Comment: The second part of my comment is crucial. Lda is not preprocessing technique. There is no such thing as "use svm with lda". It is like asking "can i use svm with logistic regression"  or even "can i use svm with svm". Unless you are thinking about Latent Dirichlet Allocation (also lda but completely different thing)

Comment: Okey, thanks! Then I have three options: SVM, PCA+SVM and PCA+LDA, right?

Comment: And plenty more, but yeah. These three are fine. For completeness add pure LDA as well

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! :)

Comment: @lejlot LDA is a dimensional reduction technique and a classifier too.  pls see this link bit.ly/2CsAJI1